# HTML Form first dropdown auto change the second dropdown options

Tags: html, mysql

I have this code on the first dropdown:

```
<td align="left" style="padding-bottom:10px">
    <select name="category" id="category">
        <option selected value="Please Select">Please Select</option>           
        <option value="Cars">Cars</option>
        <option value="Trucks">Trucks</option>
        <option value="Motorcycles">Motorcycles</option>
        <option value="Boats">Boats</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

and i also have a second category with different colors for the previous option.
For example:
If i select Cars the second dropdown will appear to select "Red", "Green" or "Blue" but if i select Trucks the second dropdown will appear to select "Black" or "White" options only.

Both second dropdown options will go to the same column (Subcategory) in the mySQL DB so no Car can have the value "Black" on Subcategory column or no Truck can have the value "Red" on Subcategory column.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you need an Ajax type solution. Tie it to the 'change selection' event on the first control. Use the result to query the available values for the second (and subsequent) controls.

Comment: Hard to help without more information. What's the backend language? PHP? what have you tried? do you use jquery? etc...

Comment: the backend language is php. im not using jQuery because didnt need it till now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/7YeL6/4/

Given this structure:

```
     <select name="category" id="category">
    <option selected value="Please Select">Please Select</option>           
    <option value="Cars">Cars</option>
    <option value="Trucks">Trucks</option>
    <option value="Motorcycles">Motorcycles</option>
    <option value="Boats">Boats</option>
</select>

<div>
<select name="category2" id="truck" class="second">
        <option value="white">white</option>
        <option value="black">black</option>            
</select>

<select name="category2" id="car" class="second">
        <option value="red">red</option>
        <option value="green">green</option>
        <option value="blue">blue</option>           
</select>
</div>
```

You could use jQuery `.change` function:

```
       $("#category").change(function () {
  var str = "";
str =  $("select#category option:selected").text();
    if(str == "Trucks"){
        $("select.second").not("#truck").hide();
        $("#truck").show();
        $("#truck").fadeIn(1000);
    }
    else if(str == "Cars"){
        $("select.second").not("#car").hide();
        $("#car").show();
        $("#car").fadeIn(1000);
    }

})
```

**CSS**

```
#category2{
display: none;
}
```

Comment: How does this adapt to selecting cars.. then trucks.. ?

Comment: i went to js fiddle and when select an option the popup appears with message with the selected option, i get it. but i dont know how to code the new dropdown for each option. can you please provide me the code to a new dropdown to be generated with different results or show the me way throw some guide or something? New at the  game, sorry

Comment: Select trucks - it will work. You can change it to make it work for other values too.

Comment: @ethrbunny This example will load a new set of select options if the user selects "Trucks". The OP can change it for the many other items he has. This shows him how to do it.

Comment: ma'man this looks and works like a charm ;) but taking the opportunity, what if i want a second dropdown to appear instead of being replaced like its happening at the moment? Never thought on "replacing" instead of "adding" a new droplist, but now im with second thoughts of what to use. But it would be great if i can manage to do both and then decide. Once again thank you!!!

Comment: @BrunoCarvalho Then just remove the `.hide` line in the jQuery function. That will cause the original to remain, while fading in the second `<select>`

Comment: oh, ok... i tried to change the code on fiddle and it didnt work, i probably explained it wrong. My intention is if you select truck, the dropdown where the "Truck" option is in, stays in the same place and a new dropdownlist appears with the black and white options. So if i change my mind and select Cars, the second dropdown that appeared before with black and white will now have the "Red", "Green" and "Blue" options for example.

Comment: @BrunoCarvalho All set - check the last comment.

Comment: oh my god. almost there!! please forgive me for being a pin in the ass but this is the closest solution i've been to solve this issue and you seem to know it good. now 2 new dropdowns appear, great (better than no dropdowns at all =] ). what i need to this being perfect is to eliminate de third dropdown (now at the moment with the "red" option, so when i select trucks, only 1 dropdown appears with Black and White, and if i select Cars instead of Trucks, the Black and White options are replaced with Red, Green and Blue. Thank you very much m8. trying it for days searching pure HTML solution =//

Comment: IT WORKS! Its just like i imagined! Awesome dude! Thanks!!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26888/discussion-between-bruno-carvalho-and-evan)

Comment: if you are still there Evan, i would need a little bit of help with you dont mind